# How to evaluate this integral for variable $a$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I am wondering how to evaluate
$$\int_0^t(t-s)^{-a}\sin(t-s)ds$$
for $a>0$. If $a=1$ this is just the sine integral. Is there some way of doing it for a variable $a$? I plugged it in to the WolframAlpha integrator and it gave me the gamma function,
$$\frac{i}{2}[ \Gamma(1-a,i(s-t)) - \Gamma(1-a,i(t-s))]\Bigr|_{s=0}^t $$
but I think this is wrong because the first argument of the incomplete gamma function has to be a positive integer.

Comment: Use convolution over laplace transform

Comment: "the first argument of the incomplete gamma function has to be a positive integer" - are you sure about that?